# System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, transactions

Please see the code below:

```
Dim intAddNicheMergeTotal As Integer = 0
        Dim intDeleteCount As Integer
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 200, 0)
        Dim transOp As New TransactionOptions
        transOp.Timeout = ts
        Using scope = New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOp)
'Do some work, which takes about 35 minutes
scope.complete
End Using
```

The code above is throwing an exception at the scope.complete line: `System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout`

Why is the transaction aborting?  I have set the timeout period to 200 minutes.

Comment: Are you sure something else is not blocking `your work`? For example, imagine other users are executing processes that are using the same tables like you, which causes you query to wait for resources to be released. Of course, this depends on the operations you are performing, the users activities and the database isolation level.

Comment: What is the maxTimeout setting in the system.transactions section of your machine.config? Think it defaults to 10 minutes if not specified.

Comment: @theduck, thanks.  I have not changed this setting.  Is it possible to set the timeout on a transaction by transaction  basis?

Comment: The machine.config setting is designed to allow system administrators to limit transaction timeouts I don't think you can modify it in code. You can find out what it is in code using `TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout`. You can also set it to `TimeSpan.Zero` in machine.config if you want infinite timeouts on all transactions for that machine. There is nasty workaround that uses reflection I think. Will see if I can locate it.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ajit/archive/2008/06/18/override-the-system-transactions-default-timeout-of-10-minutes-in-the-code.aspx - describes your 200 minute value (!). Reflection technique half way down - not nice!

Answer (score 3):

In the `machine.config` in the `system.transactions` section there is a `maxTimeout` setting. If no value is explicitly set then the default value of 10 minutes is used.

This setting is designed to allow system administrators to limit transaction timeouts and you can't override it in code. If you specify a higher value in code (as you have) then the lower maxTimeout setting is used instead.

You can set it to a higher value in `machine.config`, for instance:

```
 <system.transactions>
  <machineSettings maxTimeout="00:03:20" />
 </system.transactions>
```

but this change will apply to all transactions on the machine.